# How to organize MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I want to create a Wedding application, and i have a MySQL Database.
Each user can add a lot of guests. How to organize my Database? I have two options:

1. Create a table named Users with columns: email and password, then create a table named Guests with columns email and guests. In table Guests i can store an XML Node with all the guests of each user. But this seems disorganized.

2. Create new schema for each user, and create a table named Guests with columns that represents the guest (name, surname, tel, etc). And each record will be a guest.

Can you help me to choose the correct way? And explain me why.

Thank you

Comment: Why can't a user table have a one-to-many relationship to the guest table?

Comment: I never thought about this. But what if an user will have 500 guests, and will be 500 users? Doesn't matter if there will be 250.000 records? Isn't more organized if i will use a new schema for each user?

Comment: I don't really think a database like MySQL is going to blink at 250, 000 records in two tables

Answer (score 0):

Create one table named 'Guests' where you keep all Guest's data. Be sure to have an unique key for each guest, let's say guest_id.

Create the second table named 'Users' with all users data and a column called user_id.

Create the third table which will connect the first two tables. Call it Invitations. Here you will have at least two columns: `user_id` and `guest_id`. Your primary key in this table should be composed from these two columns.

So you have unique data for each guests/users in their private tables. You use the third table `invitations` to connect the first tables:

Example of third table content (`invitations`):

```
user_id   |  guest_id
----------------------
user_id_1 | guest_id_1
user_id_1 | guest_id_2
.....
user_id_2 | guest_id_1 (this guest is invited on both weddings :) )
user_id_2 | guest_id_999 (this one is only here)
```